# how to set different source and destination path to copy files for prod and testing environment in console app

Tags: c#, console-application, file-move

A simple file moving **console application** where source path and destination path is hard coded right now. I have to run this application in different environment - testing and production with different source path and destination path. how to set those path for copying or moving files. how to code or call  those path from config files in program.cs

Comment: Use `App.config` values instead of hard-coding.

Comment: Or pass as command line args

Comment: Use configuration files type  for this because it will help you when you deploy application to different environments when deploying you can set values based on the Environments using deployment tools easily .

Answer (score 0):

> source path and destination path is hard coded right now

Move them to config values.  Making use of `App.config` for environment-specific values is exactly what config files are for.  Something as simple as:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="BasePath" value="C:\some\path\" />
</appSettings>
```

In the code you'd get that value from the `System.Configuration` assembly.  Something like:

```
var basePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasePath"];
```

(Include any error checking you require to make sure it's a valid path, etc.)

Then when you need to create the full path, you'd include that value when combining with other known values, such as non-changing parts of the path or file names or whatever information you have.  Something like:

```
var sourcePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "/some/middle/part", fileName);
```

You can then use `File` operations on `sourcePath`.

Each environment would have its own `App.config` file.